# If an occurance is more than two times contiunously replace that occurance with a new word angularjs

Tags: angularjs, string, str-replace, replaceall

I have a text coming from backend with multiple breaks coming 2 breaks, 4 breaks or 6 breaks and i want to replace breaks with 2 breaks. For eg: if in a string i have four continuous breaks, then I want to replace those breaks with 2 breaks only.

I tried following code, but didn't worked:

```
TMSApp.filter('newlinesmatch', function () {
    return function(text) {
        var str = '<br>';
        var count = (text.match(/<br>/g) || []).length;
        if(count > 2){
            return String(text).replace(/<br>/g,'<br><br>');    
        }
    }
});
```

can some one help?

Comment: what is happening on html while using this?

Comment: could you reproduce problem here http://plnkr.co/edit/0zTG7k1EnEA85OY0hGps?p=preview seems working for me

Comment: Can you please check the updated plunk. eg  Input: adasddas <br><br><br><br> asdasd <br> asdasd <br> adsadasdasdsad<br><br><br>hfkdhfkdfda<br><br><br><br>dfasdsadsa.output I want is:  adasddas <br><br> asdasd <br><br> asdasd <br><br> adsadasdasdsad<br><br>hfkdhfkdfda<br><br>dfasdsadsa .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can replace any number of consecutive occurrences of `<br>` with `<br><br>` like this:

```
TMSApp.filter('newlinesmatch', function () {
    return function(text) {
        return text.replace(/(<br>)+/g, '<br><br>');
    }
});
```

NOTE: I know you mentioned that you will always be getting 2, 4, or 6 consecutive breaks. However, it is worth noting that the solution above would replace any number of consecutive occurrences (even a single one) with `<br><br>`.

EDIT:

Per the comment below with a REAL example, I have made the change below. Note that the original answer works for the originally described scenario, where the need was to replace CONSECUTIVE `<br>`s. The REAL example does not have consecutive `<br>`s since there is a space between every pair. The following code will work for that case:

```
.filter('newlinesmatch', function () {
    return function(text) {
      return text.replace(/(<br>\s*)+/g, '<br><br>');
    }
});
```

And here is a working plunker with the sample data provided:

http://plnkr.co/edit/ztcsbJoJ51ZF8FcJylbC?p=preview

Comment: The above code did not worked: my input: <p class="interactionText ng-binding" ng-bind-html="itemgrid.interaction_text | newlinesmatch">Renewable Energy Investments: A Case Study. Early adopters are 0  get the money? cars.<br><br> <br><br> Why?<br><br> <br><br> Our primary  which isand the planet.<br><br> <br><br> Where did we get the money?<br><br> <br><br> </p>.
Output I expect: Renewable Energy Investments: A Case Study. Early adopters are 0  get the money? cars.<br><br>Why?<br><br>  which isand the planet.<br><br>Where did we get the money? <br><br>